# select pyside listwidget item after it's added in python

Tags: python, list, widget, pyside

Users can append new team names to the list by entering text into the Text input and hitting enter on the keyboard.

How can I make it select the item after its added to the list? Keeping in mind each time a new item is added I would like the list to be reorder alphabetically first. Which i know how to sort alphabetically, I'm just not sure where in the code to place this.

This snippet is used in the code below to sort alphabetically...

```
# sort list by attribute name
        teamList.sort(key=lambda x: x._name, reverse=False)
```

The code contains a class Team. Here is the code...

[image]

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Info goes here...
"""

import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

# Variables
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
teamList = []


# Classes
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
Base class of team which contains 2 properties
name - name of team
members - list of team member names
"""
class Team:
    """
    One line description...
    other info....
    """
    def __init__(self, name, members=None):
        self._name = name
        if members==None:
            self._members = []

    @property
    def name(self, value):
        # add type validation lines here
        self._name = value

    @property
    def members(self, value):
        # add type validation lines here
        self._members = value


# Base widget widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
Base widget which contains 
label - describes widget
textedit - input field for appending items to list
listview - displays the list of items teams or members
"""
class NameListWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, title=None):
        super(NameListWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()
        if title!=None:
            self.listLabel.setText(title)

    def initUI(self): 

        # formatting 
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Input List")

        # widgets
        self.listLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Label")
        self.nameInput = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.nameList = QtGui.QListWidget()

        # signals
        self.nameInput.returnPressed.connect(self.pressed_return)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.listLabel)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.nameInput)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.nameList)
        self.show()

    def pressed_return(self):
        txt = self.nameInput.text()
        # remove leading and trailing whitespaces
        txt = txt.strip()
        # replace all remaining spaces with underscores
        txt = txt.replace (" ", "_")

        if (len(txt) >= 1):
            self.nameList.addItem(txt)
            self.nameInput.clear()


# Main widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
Main team widget contains two instances of the nameList widget
left widget - contains a list of the team names
right widget - contains list of members names for the selected team
"""
class TeamsWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TeamsWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self): 

        # formatting 
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Teams")

        # widgets
        self.teamsListWidget = NameListWidget("Teams")

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.teamsListWidget)
        self.show()

        self.populateUI()

    def populateUI(self):
        A = Team("Zebras")
        B = Team("Donuts")
        C = Team("Characters")
        D = Team("50")
        teamList.append(A)
        teamList.append(B)
        teamList.append(C)
        teamList.append(D)

        # sort list by attribute name
        teamList.sort(key=lambda x: x._name, reverse=False)

        self.teamsListWidget.nameList.clear()
        for t in teamList:
            self.teamsListWidget.nameList.addItem(t._name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TeamsWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can select the item from the last input's text:

```
def pressed_return(self):
    txt = self.nameInput.text()
    # remove leading and trailing whitespaces
    txt = txt.strip()
    # replace all remaining spaces with underscores
    txt = txt.replace (" ", "_")

    if (len(txt) >= 1):
        self.nameList.addItem(txt)
        self.nameInput.clear()

    # EDITS HERE
    items = [self.nameList.item(i).text() for i in range( self.nameList.count() ) ] # Get text of all items
    if txt in items: # Check if text is in list
        index = items.index(txt) # Get text's index
        self.nameList.item(index).setSelected(True) # Select item
```

The idea is that it will get a list of each row's text, get the row of the new item, then select it. If you want it to perform faster you could save the item's text as you're adding them in to keep track of them. This way you don't need to fetch it from the table every time you add a new item. Right now this will fail if you add a text that already exists in the list, so you may need a condition check for that.

You would have to re-order your script so that it re-sorts the items when you add a new item to it (as oppose to being in `populateUI` right now).